# JQuery .animate() modifying properties not included in code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to create an animation that compresses a header along the x-axis until the width and height are 50px, then expand along the y-axis to create a sidebar with a width of 50px if the window is scrolled down and the reverse happens when the window is scrolled back to the top.

The animation goes fine when the user scrolls down from 0 but when the window is scrolled back to the top the second `animate()` method in `ShowHeader()` adds `height: 100%` to the element even though only `width: 100%` is specified so the header fills the page.

I'm wondering where the animate() method gets the instruction to modify the height when only the width is specified.

```
$(function HideHeader() {
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('header').animate({
            "width": "50px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            complete: function () {
                $("#navtop").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                    $('header').animate({
                        "height": "100%"
                    }, {
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function () {
                            $("#navside").fadeIn("fast");

                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        });
    }

});

});

$(function HideHeader() {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $('header').animate({
            "height": "50px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            complete: function () {
                $("#navside").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                    $('header').animate({
                        "width": "100%"
                    }, {
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function () {
                            $("#navtop").fadeIn("fast");

                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        });
    }


});

});
```

There is also a JSFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ERDesign/bm84y/1/

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: hmm... it seems to be ignoring your animation from 100% height to 50px.

Comment: Ah, timing issue. If you slow things down and do the scrolling slowly, it works.

Comment: Slowly working through this(http://jsfiddle.net/bm84y/2/), adding a .stop makes it work consistantly, but buggers the animation because you're constantly stopping and starting it. you'll need to add funcationality to immediately start the animation when it starts scrolling down, but not start it again or stop it unless it starts to scroll in the opposite direction. I have a feeling doing this with css will be far less complex.

Answer (score 0):

it is about sequencing animation , a basic solution is :

```
$(function HideHeader() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('header').animate({
                "width": "50px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                complete: function () {
                    $("#navtop").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                        $('header').animate({
                            "height": "100%"
                        }, {
                            queue: false,
                            complete: function () {
                                $("#navside").fadeIn("fast");

                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            });
        }

    });

});

$(function HideHeader() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
            $('header').animate({
                "width": "100%"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                complete: function () {
                    $("#navside").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                        $('header').animate({"height": "50px"

                        }, {
                            queue: false,
                            complete: function () {
                                $("#navtop").fadeIn("fast");

                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            });
        }


    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bm84y/3/

althought using pure css is more recommended , or even using transit.js

i would recommend this though

```
#header{
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 0.4s;
}
```

and instead of using animate just use `css("height","50px")` with `css("width","100%")` and `css("height","100%")`  with `css("width","50px")`